# Electrooptic Tensor, Relating Tensors to Orientations

Tags: tensor-calculus, optical-materials

So I'm trying to gain a better understanding of electrooptic tensors:

An example of a quartz electrooptic tensor is given.
I know in order to best implement this crystal, in order to get the highest birefringence or highest opto,piezoelectric output, I want to use the value that is largest in this tensor.


However, I don't understand how to look at the tensor and say "Ah, I want to put pressure vertically on the material" as opposed to horizontally if I wanted to use the r11 value (in the case of a piezoelectric). Whereas for the birefringent case, you're looking to know the direction of the input/output of the light.

I think there's a simple explanation to this, I'm just not aware of it and can't find any valuable resources. Feel free to use a value listed in the following tensor to describe orientations:

For wavelengths of 409-605nm r11=-.47 and r41=.20 under constant strain and r11=.174 under constant stress. 

These values were found in Marvin J. Webers text "Handbook of Optical Materials" 2003.

[image: Quartz, SiO2 tensor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote "vertical pressure" but I think you meant to write "vertical electric field", since this is for electro-optic modulation. I assume you got the $r$-tensor from the following excellent page:

http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/beyersdorf/Archive/Phys208F07/ch%207-electrooptics.pdf

To recap what that PDF says. the impermeability of a material may be tensor-expanded to first-order as a function of the ambient electric field as 
$$\eta=\eta_0+\mbox{InverseVoigt}[\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{E}]$$ where
$$\eta_0=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\eta_{11}&0&0\\
0&\eta_{22}&0\\
0&0&\eta_{33}
\end{array}\right)$$
is the zero-field representation of the index ellipsoid coefficients in the principle-axis coordinates, $$\mathbf{r}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
r_{11}&0&0\\
-r_{11}&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
r_{41}&0&0\\
0&-r_{41}&0\\
0&-r_{11}&0
\end{array}\right)
$$
is the Voigt representation of the third-order electro-optic tensor,
$$\mathbf{E}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
E_x\\
E_y\\
E_z
\end{array}
\right)$$
is the applied electric field, and
$$\mbox{InverseVoigt}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a\\
b\\
c\\
d\\
e\\
f
\end{array}
\right)
\right]=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a&e&f\\
e&b&d\\
f&d&c
\end{array}\right)$$
is just shorthand for the operator which converts between matrix and Voigt notation.

For the quartz tensor you provided, this becomes

$$\eta=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\eta_{11}+r_{11}E_x&-r_{41}E_y&-r_{11}E_y\\
-r_{41}E_y&\eta_{22}-r_{11}E_x&r_{41}E_x\\
-r_{11}E_y&r_{41}E_x&\eta_{33}
\end{array}\right).$$
As you can see, there is no z-dependence.

Now, obviously this matrix is not a diagonal matrix, but by the Spectral Theorem we can rotate our coordinate system to give new principal axes for the non-zero field crystal. The 3 eigenvalues of $\eta$ are the impermittivities of the field-stressed crystal. Likewise, since there is no $z$-dependence, we can parametrize our field as $$\mathbf{E}(\theta)=|\mathbf{E}|\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\mbox{Cos}(\theta)\\
\mbox{Sin}(\theta)\\
0
\end{array}
\right).$$

Now, you said that you wanted to maximize the amount of birefringence, correct? For that, you want to find $\theta$ which maximizes the difference between the minimum and maximum eigenvalue; the relevant physical birefringence plane is given by the space spanned by the two eigenvectors corresponding to those eigenvalues.

I was too lazy to actually look up the refractive indices and electro-optical activities of quartz, but you can do that yourself. I made a Mathematica notebook which computes the impermittivities and plots them as a function of field angle and inserted random, wildly-unphysical numbers for the crystal. The plot looks something like this for zero-field:

[image]

And something like this for a huge field:

[image]

As you can see, there is a splitting from uniaxial to biaxial behavior when the field is applied, although obviously the numbers I used are fictitious, so you'll need to use the real numbers from reference tables to get physically useful info on actual quartz.

The link to the code I used to generate these images is here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fn35y4ifbdb0ztz/Electro-Optic%20Tensor%20of%20Quartz.nb

Anyways, I hope you find the code useful. It's currently configured for quartz, but you can just change the electro-optic tensor entries to whatever you need, so it's completely general for all types of crystals. I also included an example plot for KDP using its actual physical parameters.

Comment: Note: I'm actually having trouble finding the actual electro-optic coefficients of quartz with Google. Does anyone know what $r_{11}$ and $r_{41}$ for quartz are?

Comment: I was working with Saleh's book but I yanked the image from that PDF, thank you for citing the article for me.
Also my math must be kind of rusty. I'm not familiar with the Spectral Theorem but will do some research, and I totally forget how to parameterize. Regardless...
Once I install Mathematica I'll look into your notebook to see if it makes more sense, since Notepad++ can't read it appropriately. I really appreciate all your help!

Comment: Really can't thank you enough. This was so helpful. This is the kind of worked example that I've been looking for in every textbook. I just didn't have the math background to recognize some of this (i.e. Inverse voigt or spectral theorem). Fantastic! Thank you!

Comment: My answer probably is a bit sideways, since if you're doing electro-optic modulation then you're trying to find the field orientation which maximizes the derivative of the birefringence as a function of applied electric field, whereas my code sort of did the reverse, which was plot the impermittivities (from which the birefringence can be found) versus orientation for a fixed electric field. Also, I'm sure there's probably a simple way of looking at the tensor and saying "oh, it'd work best this way" but I don't work in NLO (I'm a chemist) so my expertise is lacking.

Comment: If you have any other questions or still don't get something feel free to ask. I slightly updated the Dropbox file. BTW, the birefringence, or difference between the maximum and minimum indices of refraction, is $\lambda_1^{-1/2}-\lambda_3^{-1/2}$ where $\lambda_1$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $\eta$ and $\lambda_3$ is the largest eigenvalue of $\eta$.

Comment: @Sean: I just realized my definition of InverseVoigt had the $e$ and $f$ switched, and thus is wrong. I updated it in the Mathematica notebook, though.